# Any recommendations for smoke detectors with wireless remote alarms?

Tags: safety, product-recommendation

I would like to put a smoke detector in my attached garage and barn, with a wireless/remote signal with a a receiver inside the house.

So far I have [found this one](http://www.lowes.com/pd_84145-65213-0919-9999_4294825631+4294855722__?productId=1102111)

[image]

I am assuming that with that one, you buy some number of them (maybe 2 or 3 in my case) and they all broadcast to each other?

Are there any other similar products that you have experience using?

Comment: I would not recommend installation of a smoke dector in the garage or the barn.  Smoke detectors monitor particles in the air and could be set off by vehicle exhaust or dust. A heat detector would best be used for applicaitons in a garge or barn.

Comment: Thanks.  One issue is that it could get quite cold out there (well below freezing certain times of the year, like right now actually!)... I wonder if that affects the smoke detector in any way... hmm...   The "garage" part is partitioned from the main barn area, so I wouldn't normally have to worry about car exhaust, but it could be an issue under some conditions or if I bring a car into the main part to work on-- thanks for that note.

Comment: In very cold environments, batteries in wireless sensors die.  We have trouble with outdoor temperature sensors.  The safe temperature range for alkaline has a surprisingly high low-end.

Comment: Photoelectric smoke detectors are the recommended way to go these days.  Ionization smoke detectors are prone to false alarms and require a small amount of a radioactive isotope in them to function.

Comment: This was enlightening.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrOLxh8GuCU

Answer (score 2):

I have *[First Alert Onelink](http://www.firstalert.com/detectors/battery/onelink-2109942317/SCO501CN-3ST)* in my home. It has a voice notification that indicates the location of the module activated to all other modules. (I have 4 in my home) There are hard-wired and battery powered units. They also use a photoelectric smoke sensor that reduces nuisance alarms from normal smoke or steam.

I personally don't know about the barn issue or the wireless range; but they have quite a few options among the models on the First Alert site.

Answer (score 1):

I wired a remote siren to the smoke detector in our attached shed, so that we will be alerted in the house if there is a fire in the shed. Seven dollar basic smoke alarm, $5.00 piezo from radio shack, some wire, a relay, and an extra 9v battery. It's pretty easy to do.

Comment: Really great answer. Do you have some references on how to build something like this based on your products?

Answer (score 1):

I tested the [First Alert Onelink](http://www.firstalert.com/faqs/onelink%20First%20Alert%20OneLink) and the Kidde Wireless System side by side for range.  I was able to get over 300 feet.  The Kidde system is older and is a direct radio link.  The First Alert system can 'hop' from detector to detector, so you can form a chain of units each 300 feet apart.  Just get two or more units and they talk to each other.

Or: if you get a hardwire unit, you can use the interconnect wire to trigger just about anything (e.g. a garage door opener, siren, radio, alarm system, etc).

Or: get a BRK HD6135FB heat detector (no problem with cold weather or condensation!) and wire it to a OneLink alarm.  If the HD6135FB goes off, it activates the OneLink, which relays the message to all linked alarms.